# Standard draw-on-canvas program, offset caused by docked UI elements. How to dynamically compensate?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm learning WPF, and made (following a couple SO posts) a simple program where you draw with the mouse.  I have a DockPanel with top and left panes, and the drawing canvas taking up the remaining space.  When I click and drag to draw freeform curves, the drawing of the line is offset by the amount of space taken up by the menus.  I'd rather not hardcode values, since those sizes are liable to change.

```
private void Canvas_MouseDown_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
     if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
      {
          offset = e.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement);
          Console.WriteLine("Offset: " + offset.ToString());
          currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
      }
}

private void Canvas_MouseMove_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
      {
            Line line = new Line();
            line.Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
            line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
            line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
            line.X2 = e.GetPosition(this).X;
            line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(this).Y;

            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

            canvas.Children.Add(line);
      }
}
```

Is there a way to directly get the point in the canvas element rather than the program window as a whole?  If not, I could get the draw-width and draw-height of the menu elements, but that doesn't seem like the most elegant solution.

Thanks!

Comment: is `e.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement)` not correctly returning the values relative to just the `Canvas`? I see you use that once, but then use `e.GetPosition(this)` otherwise, which would return it relative to the entire `Window` (or whatever 'this' is).

Comment: Ah, I'm dumb.  That was, but before when I set currentPoint to e.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement), I forgot to copy it down below to the MouseMove function.  ><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think you should be doing:

```
private void Canvas_MouseDown_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
     if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
      {
          offset = e.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement);
          Console.WriteLine("Offset: " + offset.ToString());
          currentPoint = e.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement); //  Change here
      }
}

private void Canvas_MouseMove_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
      {
            Line line = new Line();
            line.Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
            line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
            line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
            line.X2 = e.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement).X; //  Change here
            line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement).Y; //  Change here

            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement); //  Change here

            canvas.Children.Add(line);
      }
}
```

`MouseButtonEventArgs.GetPosition` and [`MouseEventArgs.GetPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.getposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) both take an object that they use to determine the "relative" coordinates of the mouse event. So if you pass in `this` - which I'm assuming is your window - it will be relative to the entire `Window`. If you pass in `sender` - which is your `Canvas` for these events - it will be relative to the `Canvas`.
Since your `Line` objects will be positioned relative to the `Canvas` that is their parent, you want your coordinates to be relative to that point (the upper-left corner of the `Canvas`)

Comment: Yup, just spotted my mistake, and this was it.  Thanks!